# Select rows with duplicate values in 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [Test].[dbo].[MyTest]
(
[Id]    BIGINT NOT NULL,
[FId]   BIGINT NOT NULL,
[SId]   BIGINT NOT NULL
);
```

And some data:

```
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (1, 100, 11); 
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (2, 200, 12); 
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (3, 100, 21); 
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (4, 200, 22);
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (5, 300, 13); 
INSERT INTO  [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] ([Id], [FId], [SId]) VALUES (6, 200, 12);
```

So I need 2 select query,

First Select FId, SId that like a distinct in both column so the result is:

```
100, 11
200, 12
100, 21
200, 22
300, 13
```

As you see the values of `200, 12` returned once.

Second query is the Id's of that columns whose duplicated in both FId, SId So the result is:

```
2
6
```

Does any one have any idea about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Fid,SId 
FROM MyTest
```

Second query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a1.Id
FROM MyTest a1 INNER JOIN MyTest a2
    ON a1.Fid = a2.Fid 
   AND a1.SId = a2.SId
   AND a1.Id <> a2.Id
```

I cannot test them, but I think they should work...

Comment: The DISTINCT in the 2nd query adds overhead: it fixes a poor JOIN. This won't scale because of that. It's a simple aggregate and self join

Answer (score 9):

Standard SQL

```
SELECT
    M.ID
FROM
    ( -- note all duplicate FID, SID pairs
    SELECT FID, SID
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY FID, SID
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
    ) T
    JOIN -- back onto main table using these duplicate FID, SID pairs
    MyTable M ON T.FID = M.FID AND T.SID = M.SID
```

Using windowing:

```
SELECT 
    T.ID
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        ID,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FID, SID) AS CountPerPair
    FROM
        MyTable
    ) T
WHERE
   T.CountPerPair > 1
```

Comment: +1 for handling multiple identical rows (3 or more) without splashing/abusing distinct

Answer (score 1):

first:

```
select distinct FId,SId from [Test].[dbo].[MyTest]
```

second query

```
select distinct t.Id
from [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] t
inner join [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] t2
on t.Id<>t2.Id and t.FId=t2.FId and t.SId=t2.SId
```

Comment: I think on second query you should use `DISTINCT`, because if duplicated rows are more than two you get same id more than once. Am I right?

Comment: No, I mean: if OP has ids 2, 6 and 8 with same FId and SId, your query without `DISTINCT` returns every id twice (so 2, 2, 6, 6, 8, 8). I cannot test it but I'm pretty sure...

Answer (score 0):

Part 1 is as mentioned above distinct.

This will resolve second part.

```
select id from [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] a 
where exists(select 1 from [Test].[dbo].[MyTest] where a.[SId] = [SId] and a.[FId] = [FId] and a.id <> id)
```